# Custom url structure for custom template

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permalinks, templates, redirect

I have a custom taxonomy called **activities** and a custom role called **operator**.
So, if [example.com/operators/bird-watching](http://#) is visited then I want to list all the operators that offers bird-watching. Bird-watching is a term of activities taxonomy. 
I have made a different template for this. I have also developed a url structure for this which is show below. All I want now is to load my custom template if someone visits [example.com/operators/bird-watching](http://#)

Tried this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173498/custom-template-for-custom-url) but no help.

```
function resources_cpt_generating_rule($wp_rewrite) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $rules = array();
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'activities',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

    $post_type = 'operator';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $rules['operators/' . $term->slug . '/([^/]*)$'] = 'index.php?operators/'.$term->slug;            
    }
    // merge with global rules
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'resources_cpt_generating_rule' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you attached, you have everything you need. You should:

- add query variable (e.g `operators_actv`),
- add rewrite rule that sets this variable (`operators_actv`),
- use the `template_include` action hook to load custom template if query variable `operators_actv` is set.

**Code**:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'se332319_custom_query_vars' );
add_filter( 'template_include', 'se332319_custom_template', 50 );
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'se332319_resources_cpt_generating_rule' );

function se332319_resources_cpt_generating_rule( $wp_rewrite ) 
{
    $rules = [
        'operators/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?operators_actv=$matches[1]&activities=$matches[1]'
    ];
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;

    return $wp_rewrite;
}

function se332319_custom_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    array_push( $query_vars, 'operators_actv' );
    return $query_vars;
}

function se332319_custom_template( $template )
{
    $qv = get_query_var('operators_actv', null);
    if ( $qv !== null && term_exists($qv, 'activites') !== null ) {

        // use "get_stylesheet_directory()" or "get_template_directory()"
        // if template file is in theme directory 
        $template =  dirname(__FILE__) . '/se332319_custom_template.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Don't forget to refresh permalinks. Click **Save** in `Dashboars -> Settings -> Permalinks` or do it from code with `flush_rewrite_rules()` ([how to recreate rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Usage)).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply as well as help. Now, what will be my new url according to this code? I tried abc.com/operators/cannoying/ but it is returning 404.

Comment: @saurav.rox If `cannoying` is a term taxonomy `activites`, then `abc.com/operators/cannoying/` should work. Did you flush the rewrite rules (Settings -> Permalinks -> Save)?

Comment: I changed this `'operators/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?operators_actv=$matches[1]'` to `'customslug/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?operators_actv=$matches[1]'` and now I can see index.php with blog posts loaded when I visit `abc.com/customslug/cannoying/`. Moreover, `die` is not called inside  `if ( $qv !== null && term_exists($qv, 'activites') !== null ) {`. I flushed the permalinks as well.

Comment: @saurav.rox Sorry for typo, taxonomy slug should be `activities`, not `activites`.

Comment: The code worked. I should have checked the typo as well. Anyways, is there a quick way to add body_class on such custom template? And then I will mark it as resolved.

Comment: @saurav.rox There is another way if you do not have to treat `abc.com/operators/cannoying/` and `abc.com/activities/cannoying/` differently. Then just add `rewrite => ['slug' => 'operators']` to the `register_taxonomy()` and rename your template to `taxonomy-activities.php`.

Comment: I have already that template called `taxonomy-activities.php`. So, I was trying to add a different template. Now, I want to add body_class on such custom template. Is it possible.

Comment: @saurav.rox Use ["body_class" filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) and check there if your query var `operators_actv` exists and is valid, then add custom CSS class.

Comment: Ok. Thank you a lot for your help. Marking it as resolved.